# AWS:Storm cluster can not be deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-storm

I want to deploy storm cluster on AWS,and i followed this instructions https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-deploy/wiki.When i launching a clusters using this command:

```
lein deploy-storm --start --name mycluster --branch 0.8.3
```

then i getting error

```
INFO  provision - Attaching to Available Cluster...
Can't find 'backtype.storm.provision' as .class or .clj for lein run: please check the spelling.
ERROR logging - Exception in thread "main"
ERROR logging - java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/winoria1/.storm/storm.yaml (Permission denied) (form-init5499008113743341564.clj:1)
ERROR logging - at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5440)
ERROR logging - at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5415)
ERROR logging - at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:5857)
ERROR logging - at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:5820)
ERROR logging - at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:221)
ERROR logging - at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:226)
ERROR logging - at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:254)
ERROR logging - at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:279)
ERROR logging - at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:354)
ERROR logging - at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:422)
ERROR logging - at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:369)
ERROR logging - at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:165)
ERROR logging - at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:482)
ERROR logging - at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
ERROR logging - Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/winoria1/.storm/storm.yaml (Permission denied)
ERROR logging - at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
ERROR logging - at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
ERROR logging - at clojure.java.io$fn__7470.invoke(io.clj:224)
ERROR logging - at clojure.java.io$fn__7394$G__7370__7401.invoke(io.clj:63)
ERROR logging - at clojure.java.io$fn__7482.invoke(io.clj:257)
ERROR logging - at clojure.java.io$fn__7394$G__7370__7401.invoke(io.clj:63)
ERROR logging - at clojure.java.io$fn__7444.invoke(io.clj:160)
ERROR logging - at clojure.java.io$fn__7420$G__7374__7427.invoke(io.clj:63)
ERROR logging - at clojure.java.io$writer.doInvoke(io.clj:113)
ERROR logging - at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:411)
ERROR logging - at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
ERROR logging - at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:133)
ERROR logging - at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
ERROR logging - at clojure.core$spit.doInvoke(core.clj:5385)
ERROR logging - at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:426)
ERROR logging - at backtype.storm.provision$sync_storm_conf_dir.invoke(provision.clj:50)
ERROR logging - at backtype.storm.provision$attach_BANG_.invoke(provision.clj:55)
ERROR logging - at backtype.storm.provision$start_with_nodes_BANG_.invoke(provision.clj:85)
ERROR logging - at backtype.storm.provision$start_BANG_.invoke(provision.clj:91)
ERROR logging - at backtype.storm.provision$_main$fn__8422.invoke(provision.clj:144)
ERROR logging - at backtype.storm.provision$_main.doInvoke(provision.clj:130)
ERROR logging - at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:483)
ERROR logging - at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:381)
ERROR logging - at user$eval5$fn__7.invoke(form-init5499008113743341564.clj:1)
ERROR logging - at user$eval5.invoke(form-init5499008113743341564.clj:1)
ERROR logging - at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5424)
ERROR logging - ... 13 more
```

plz help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have some sort of permissions problem: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/winoria1/.storm/storm.yaml (Permission denied)
Are you running as user winoria1? Make sure you have read/write access to the home directory, .storm and storm.yaml.

Comment: i know,it a permission issue.but winoria user have all the permission read/write.

Comment: what is the output of ls -al /home/winoria1/.storm/?

Comment: output is "ls -al /home/winoria1/.storm/storm.yaml"

Comment: thanks @bridiver its working for me.problem in my ~/.pallet/config.clj file